# How to point thousands of root domains to a target domain name on Google Cloud DNS? (ANAME or ALIAS alternatives?)

Tags: domain-name-system, google-cloud-platform, aname-record

I am trying to setup DNS records on for a large number of zones, where the apex (root) of the zone points to a resource on another Cloud Providers platform, the IP addresses of which might change over time.

Other managed DNS services provider so-called `ANAME` or `ALIAS` records, where the resource's domain name is stored, and `A` records are getting dynamically synthesized by periodically resolving the stored domain name (on the side of the managed DNS provider).

Since I have not found this functionality to be available on Google Cloud DNS: how would I go about accomplishing this in other ways?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Cloud DNS does not support CNAME or ALIAS records for the zone apex (example.com).

Technically, ALIAS records at the zone apex is a DNS violation.

> how would I go about accomplishing this in other ways?

1. Use a different DNS provider that supports ALIAS records.
2. Cloudflare states that they do support this for AWS, Azure and Google Cloud.
3. DNS Made Easy states they support ANAME.
4. Create an instance in the cloud that your point your records to. This instance does a redirect to the designed domain. This is not fault-tolerant but very cheap. This also only works with HTTP/HTTPS protocols.